# is there a way to use a for loop to have each LED blink upon pressing a button?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I have been having problems with the timing of the LEDs. I assume this is also a timing problem. I have the following error and code. The way I thought about it was that it would run through every element of the array 'LED_PIN' and it would execute the function 'blink()' when I pressed the button down. However, I believe this is not possible due to the fact that the for loop would be over by the time I press the button. Still, the code should work, only that I wouldn't get a chance to press the button in time to make a LED blink.

Error:

```
 RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel first
```

.......

Code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def blink(led):
    GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    GPIO.output(led, GPIO.LOW)
    previous_button_state +=1
    if(previous_button_state > 2):
        previous_button_state = 0

previous_button_state = 0

LED_PIN = [17, 22, 27]
BUTTON_PIN = 26

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(LED_PIN[0], GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED_PIN[1], GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(LED_PIN[2], GPIO.OUT)


for i in LED_PIN:
    if(GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN == GPIO.HIGH)):
       blink(i)


GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: You need to have an infinite loop that is checking if you press the button, then execute blink(). Otherwise you could also use interrupts to trigger blink when the button is pressed so you don't have to constantly check the pin.

Comment: Also, when you press the button, which of the 3 LEDS are supposed to blink? The three of them?

Comment: `GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN == GPIO.HIGH)` looks weird. Python maybe interprets it as `GPIO.input(False)`, hence the setup error. Try `GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN) == GPIO.HIGH` instead.

Comment: Wonderful. Now if I can just get the for loop to work (have each pressing of the button light up the subsequent LED). I tried 'time.sleep(0.5)' in the 'for' loop, but no success.

Comment: Update your question with the new code, since there's still no infinite loop and the `==GPIO.HIGH` is still inside the input instead of outside as suggested by nagyl